# How to use value of a C# variable in XAML in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie in Xamarin.forms as well as in C#, I am creating a user account page with Xaml named userac.xaml, in which there will be a label saying, "Hello, [name of user]" and their is a string variable in userac.xaml.cs which contains the name of user which will be displayed in  userac.xaml page as "Hello, [name of user]", but I can't figure out how to do so. Please Help.

I have attached the code:-

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text=""
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
```

userac.xaml.cs:-

```
public partial class userac : ContentPage
{
    public Contracts()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you read up on [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/) within Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use data binding.
Also, as you said you are a newbie to the C# language, so if you are not familiar with **C#** **Properties** declaration you can see in the example (the `get()` and `set()` methods inside the code) please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Please see comments inside the example based on your code:

**.XAML:**

```
 <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="{Binding TheUserName}"
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
          HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
  </StackLayout>
```

**.CS:**

```
public partial class userac : ContentPage
{
    private string _TheUserName = "Some User Name";
    public string TheUserName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Hello " + _TheUserName;
        }
        set
        {
            _TheUserName = value;
            // read here about OnPropertyChanged built-in method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.onpropertychanged?view=xamarin-forms
            OnPropertyChanged("TheUserName");
        }
    }

    public userac()
    {
        // Note: binding context can also to another view model class of this view, but here we will use the class of this specific view
        // So, you can also do something like that:
        // BindingContext = new useracViewModel() 
        BindingContext = this;
        // you can also change the default value of _TheUserName by getting it from database, xml file etc...
        TheUserName = GetCurrentUserName();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string GetCurrentUserName()
    {
        // ...
        // do things to retrieve the user name...
        // ...
        return "John Doe";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir for replying, and really sorry for this childish question, do i have to place this whole sample code in my userac.xaml.cs file or i have to add this part of code:-                
  public MainPage()
    { 
        BindingContext = this;
        TheUserName = GetCurrentUserName();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string GetCurrentUserName()
    {
        return "John Doe";
    }
}   in my MainPage.xaml.cs

Comment: @GautamSaxena This is very good question because I was wrong in the constructor name (sorry I took it from some project in my VS), please see the change in my original answer! - `public MainPage()` constructor signature was replaced with the correct signature to:  `public userac()` and all the c# code must be in the userac cs file.

Comment: Thank you very very much, Sir, you solved my problem, It worked successfully, Its really productive to be in touch with you, again thanx alot sir.